# WinError2 не удается найти указанный файл

Tags: python

Пытаюсь запустить несколько скриптов с помощью subprocess, но выбивает ошибку, в чем может быть проблема?

Вот код программы:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess
from subprocess import sys

try:
   
    subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe','C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer.py'])
except Exception as e:
    print ('Process failed',e)
try:
    subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe','C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer.py'])
except Exception as e:
    print ('Process failed',e)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer.py", line 81, in <module>
    items = parse(url)
  File "C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer.py", line 32, in parse
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Путь верный, смотрел через

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: и что показало print(sys.executable) ?

Comment: как вариант поставь перед каждым путем ``r``, так, чтобы было ``r'C:\.......'``

Comment: Вот что показал sys. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe`

Comment: Вариант с `r` перед путем помог, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было довольно простое, спасибо за это Эникейщику, нужно было перед ссылкой на `python.exe` добавить `r`

Примерно вот так:

```
try:
   
    subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe','C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer.py'])
except Exception as e:
    print ('Process failed',e)
```